# How do I stop all other Plyr instances except this one

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, plyr

I set up this little javascript to initialize a couple of players on my webpage and add an event to make only one player active while everything else is paused. This is supposed to emulate the "autpoause" function which, for some reason, is only available on Vimeo videos, but not Youtube videos:

```
    const players = Plyr.setup(".myplayer", { fullscreen: { enabled: false }, autopause: true });


    $('players').each(function(index, players) {

        players[index].on('play', function(index, players, event) {

          players.not(this).each(function(index, players) {

            players[index].pause();

          });

        });

    });
```

Somehow, nothing really happens. The `.not(this)` is supposed to select all other instances except the one I am declaring the event listener on. But when I try it out, nothing is paused. All the other players keep playing.

What am I doing wrong? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What does `console.log($('players').length)` give you?   Looks like it should be `$(".players")`

Comment: Can you tell use what library you are using for `Plyr.setup` as it doesn't seem relevant to the [tag:plyr] tag.

Comment: Latest revision I think. https://openbase.com/js/plyr

Comment: console.log doesn't output anything. not sure why. but overall, the players work and I can start/stop them. it is just not possible to stop everything else just to get the one player active I just clicked on.

Comment: Where did you add the console.log?  Just put it in the console once the page has loaded.  Ideally, add it *before* your `$('players').each` line, not inside the each/callback.

Comment: ok that gives me an error: Uncaught TypeError: players[index] is undefined

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by using non-jQuery code:

`players.forEach((player, index) => player.on('play', () => players.filter((p, i) => i !== index).forEach((p) => p.pause())))`

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
<video controls crossorigin playsinline preload="false" class="player">
   <source src="VIDEO_PATH" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
*/

// Init plyr
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.player')).map(p => new Plyr(p));

//Handle play/pause event
for (let index = 0; index < players.length; index++) {
    players[index].on('play', function() {
       console.log('Play')
       for (let index2 = 0; index2 < players.length; index2++) {
          if (index != index2) {
             players[index2].pause(); // Pause other plyr instances
          } 
       }
    })
}
```